# Kafka streaming on MS-SQl CDC data

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka

How can we handle `MS-SQL 2008 CDC`(change Data capture) with Kafka streaming?
Any best use cases will help us to test in out environment.

Comment: CDC and Kafka are both tools that can be applied to a variety of situations. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy. Confluent has written a tool that works with Postgres CDC and Kafka, called [Bottled Water](https://www.confluent.io/blog/bottled-water-real-time-integration-of-postgresql-and-kafka/), but it doesn't currently support MSSQL CDC. It's open source, so it's possible you could use it as a template for a Roll Your Own solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a prototype for capturing changes from SQL Server and streaming it to Kafka. [Kafka Connect JDBC source connector](https://www.confluent.io/blog/no-more-silos-how-to-integrate-your-databases-with-apache-kafka-and-cdc) is a good starting point.

Beware that it has certain limitations  that it does not capture deletes and it might miss some of the updates.

If you want a full proof approach you should stream the database transaction log which provides the complete log of all the changes committed to the database. The tools like [Debezium](http://debezium.io/) (Currently support major databases), [Golden Gate](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/overview/index.html) (Oracle) [Change data capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server) (SQL Server) provides support for streaming to Kafka.